# jQuery color style alternating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve a jQuery effect like: http://jsfiddle.net/Qcghe/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    setInterval(function() {
        $('small:nth-of-type(1)')
            .animate( { color: '#F7B903' }, 750)
            .animate( { color: '#FFF' }, 1000); 
    }, 1000);

    setInterval(function() {
        $('small:nth-of-type(2)')
            .animate( { color: '#5BB6FD' }, 750)
            .animate( { color: '#FFF' }, 1000); 
    }, 2000);

    setInterval(function() {
        $('small:nth-of-type(3)')
            .animate( { color: '#D13360' }, 750)
            .animate( { color: '#FFF' }, 1000); 
    }, 3000);

});
```

I want to animate the colour of the dots in the following order:

1. **white, white, white** (initial state)
2. **blue,  white, white**
3. **blue,  red,   white**
4. **blue,  red,   green**
5. **white, red,   green**
6. **blue,  white, green**
7. **blue,  red,   white**
8. …and back to the initial state.

I made an animated GIF in Photoshop to help illustrate (black and white are inverted):

[gif animation http://cdn.vpsunder10.com/1.gif](http://cdn.vpsunder10.com/1.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because each of them follows a similar but related cycle of animations, I'd try expressing this as one sequence of steps rather than three separate ones.

```
var $dots = $('#dots span'),
    colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green'], // Colour assigned to each dot, in order.
    step = 1000;                       // Duration of each animation step in ms.

function cycle() {
    $dots
        .finish() // Ensure no animations still running from last cycle.
        .each(function(index, dot) {
            var $dot = $(dot),
                color = colors[index];

            $dot
                .delay(index * step)
                .animate({ color: color }, step)
                .delay(step * 2)
                .animate({ color: 'white' }, step)
                .promise()
                .done(function() {
                    // All but last should be restored to dot colour.
                    if (index != 2) $dot.animate({ color: color }, step);
                })
            ;
        });

    // Set all the dots to white once animations have finished.
    $dots.promise().done(function() { $dots.animate({ color: 'white' }, step) });
}

// Start immediately, and thereafter every seven steps.
cycle();
setInterval(cycle, step * 7);
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/WEa94/)

You can make it faster or slower by playing with the `step` variable.

(If you were interested and don't have to support older browsers, I could also show you how to do this in pure CSS with keyframe animations.)

Comment: The javascript is ok but would be nice to do this with CSS for support and faster loading.

Answer (score 1):

check the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  setInterval(function() {
    $('small:nth-of-type(1)')
    .animate( { color: '#F7B903' }, 1000)
    .delay(4000)
    .animate( { color: '#FFF' }, 1000); 

     $('small:nth-of-type(2)')
    .delay(1000)
    .animate( { color: '#5BB6FD' }, 1000)
    .delay(5000)
    .animate( { color: '#FFF' }, 1000); 

      $('small:nth-of-type(3)')
    .delay(2000)
    .animate( { color: '#D13360' }, 1000)
    .delay(6000)
    .animate( { color: '#FFF' }, 1000); 

    }, 10000);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qcghe/3/

Comment: the animation is ok but the state with more than one white bullet is the initial state then only 1 white. look at the gif i added wich has black instead of white